# IRT degrees of freedom of item fit statistics

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, item-response-theory

I'm fitting Rasch models with the `mirt` package. Upon measuring item-wise $Q_1$ using `mirt::itemfit(model, fit_stats="X2")`, I noticed that items have different degrees of freedom. I thought the degrees of freedom would, in all cases, equal the number of trait bins minus the number of fit item parameters ($1$ for Rasch models). Where do the differing degrees of freedom between items come from?

Comment: There's more than one way to make a bin.... did you read the `group.bins` argument in the package documentation?

Comment: Even if I set `group.bins=10`, the items will have varying degrees of freedom even though they all have the same number of parameters, that's what I don't understand (Item 1 has 3 df, item 2 has 0, item 3 has 2, ...). I should also mention I have a lot of missing data.